# Precisely when will transport Hawk arrive at Goshen?

Tags: highfleet

I'm playing [Highfleet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HighFleet), and I'm trying to better understand the movements of the vulnerable transport ships I need to prey upon for my survival.

In this scenario, I've learned that the transport "Hawk" is traveling to the city Goshen from Erbil by way of Rafat and Aktash. Here's a diagram of the situation:

[image: Hawk's flight plan]

<sup>(Here's a [full-size screenshot](https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/1943883841543830042/EC89F3BF1B64136737AC5BB40686C97264F8AD21/?imw=5000&imh=5000&ima=fit&impolicy=Letterbox&imcolor=%23000000&letterbox=false), which might include important details I've omitted, or in case I made a mistake. Note that it's taken 54 game-minutes after I received the intel; the rest of this post accounts for that.)</sup>

Using the compass tool, I estimate the distance of each leg thus:

| **From** | **To** | **Distance (km)** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Erbil | Rafat | 681* |
| Rafat | Aktash | 1064 |
| Aktash | Goshen | 934 |

<sup>* When I received this intel, Hawk was not at Erbil, but partly between Erbil & Rafat, as shown in the diagram and screenshot. The distance listed here is the distance from *Hawk's position* to Rafat.</sup>

The total distance is 2,679 km. At Hawk's current speed of 186 kph, a journey of that distance would take 14h24m. I learned this at 6:22 am, so it's safe to assume Hawk might arrive as early as 8:46 pm (but not earlier).

My raider wing is ~2,253 km from Goshen, and travels at 559 kph, so with a travel time of 4h02m, they can easily arrive before Hawk.

This is where things get complicated. It is not safe for my raider wing to idle in Goshen for 10+ hours while waiting for Hawk to arrive; if I hang out much longer than ~8 hours, it becomes increasingly likely that the local governor will summon an enemy strike group that will wipe out my raiders and eventually my main force too. To avoid that, I'd like my raiders to arrive in Goshen ~2 hours before Hawk (so they have time to refuel before attacking).

To make matters worse, I'm not even sure it *will* be "only" ~10 hours, because I don't know if Hawk will stop in the cities along its route, or for how long. I know from the tutorial that all the AI-controlled actors (strike groups, carriers, and transports) generally move once per day -- but those are not the exact words and I fear I'm mischaracterizing the behavior.

I'm also unsure how much to read into the transport's path as drawn by the game. Does the fact that it shows me all future three legs of the journey reveal that Hawk's flight to Goshen is non-stop? Or, will Hawk stop in each of these cities, and the reason the line stops in Goshen is simply that Hawk hasn't yet decided where it will go subsequently?

If I had a firmer understanding of transport behavior, the math and tactics in this case would fall into place easily. If you understand that behavior well enough to pinpoint Hawk's arrival for me, I assume I can infer the rest.

So, that's my question: when will Hawk arrive in Goshen, as precisely as can be anticipated from the available intelligence?